# Excel - Power Query - fill imported columns with formulas

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a Query in place, which imports some empty columns. I want those columns to be filled with some formulas, referencing other columns (from the same query).

I tried:

- "Replace Values" option, but that does not work for formulas.
- Removing the empty columns and adding them as new (non-query) columns works, but messes up the order of the columns, which needs to be the same as it is now (this is a request from the users of the file). So this was also a dead end.
- of course, I tried to enter the formula manually into the empty columns, but on refresh, the formulas were overwritten by the imported blanks (no surprise here)

Is this even possible ?

Comment: Can't you change the order of the colukns If you add the formulas in new columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Query supports adding "[Custom Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-custom-column)" which are similar to adding a formula column in excel. You can add a column in any sequence you may want and also change the sequence if required.

To help with this there is also a "[Create Column from Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-column-from-example)" where you can enter a sample output in few rows and it will automatically calculate the formula for you.

Additional resources:

- [Column from Example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-column-from-an-example-power-query-cd82c570-8da7-4d70-91a1-3827b5995eab) - with a example video
- [Custom Column](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-custom-column-power-query-2dbb579a-915b-4ebd-b622-8e7f3d1d61a6)